# Open browser with proxy setting set from Java

Tags: java

I need to open a browser from Java code. I understand this can be done as follows :

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create("http://google.com"));
```

But i need the browser to use certain proxy settings as well. (i.e. when the browser opens, its proxy settings must be set to certain values.) I tried using the follwoing code but it doesnt work :

```
public static void main(String asf[]){
    System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
    try {
        java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create("http://google.com"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("done");
}
```

Setting the proxy from command line using

```
 java -Dhttp.proxyHost=webcache.example.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
```

is not an option for me. How do i accomplish this?

Comment: setting system properties might be sufficient because Google Chrome, IE uses the system setting but browsers like Firefox have their own settings.. hence you might have to write code that will detect which system browser is getting opened and then a way to change that browsers properties

Comment: I just have to make it work for a browser that uses the system settings itself.(like chrome in my case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Chromes proxy switches can be useful here. We can just make a shortcut for the chrome browser whose target contains the switch  --proxy-server=127.0.0.1:8080 . Now this shortcut can be opened from java code using the Runtime class' exec method. The arguments  to exec will be "cmd /c start /d \"d:\" chrome.lnk" where d: is the path of my shortcut. A detailed description of this technique can be found here http://sleepingthreads.blogspot.in/2013/07/open-browser-with-proxy-settings-set.html

Note that Google states that the use of switches is not recommended. So use this as a temporary solution only.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is largely correct which deals with setting the proxy, but in case it is not working there is another way to set the proxy via Java code and that is via the proxy class.

```
SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("socks.example.com", 1080);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, addr);
Socket socket = new Socket(proxy);
InetSocketAddress dest = new InetSocketAddress("server.example.org", 1234);
socket.connect(dest);
```

Here the socket will try to connect to its destination address (server.example.org:1234) through the specified SOCKS proxy.

For more detail you can go through the **[Standard Java Documentation for Proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html)**

Your solution for opening a browser can be improved by adding a check

```
if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
{
  Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.google.com"));
}
```

this is in addition to your solution .... maybe you can call it an alternate way

```
try    { 
    Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start http://www.google.com"); 
} 
catch(IOException e1) {
    System.out.println(e1);
}
```

Comment: The browser that is opened must use the Proxy set through the code. The above code snippet will make the socket use the proxy, but the browser that will be opened will still use the old settings.